# What's the use of went on?

Tags: verbs

Despite playing for a mediocre team, he went on to score 25 goals last season.

Despite playing for a mediocre team, he scored 25 goals last season.

Are these sentences same?

What exactly is the use of 'Went on'?

does 'last season' require proposition? "in last season"?

Please ignore the second question if it does not follow the forum rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion of *went on to* implies that a particular time in the past has just been mentioned; presumably some point at the beginning of last year's football season. Something happened to the player, and in the period of time following that incident he scored 25 goals.

The second sentence just says what he did during that season.

A **preposition** isn't needed in phrases like 'last Monday', 'this week', 'last year'.

Comment: Yes; 'went on' implies a point (perhaps not exactly a given instant) in time, as in 'Despite breaking his leg at the age of 28, after rehabilitation, he went on to score105 more goals for his club.' OP's first example sentence isn't ideal.

Comment: No - I would expect something like "He joined XXX United and went on to score 25 goals that season'.

Comment: Yes, if you went on (continued, proceeded) to do something, you go from one point in time onward.